# How to correctly pass a pointer to a function?

Tags: c++, pointers

I don't know if the title fits the problem, but I think my problem is regarding to how I am passing the pointers correctly in a function. 
So I have a linked list, that is pointed by head;

Let's pretend I have this linked list, pointed by head: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NULL}
I call the function NextNode(head), and I give the list, the result will be that head is pointing to 2. I would like that the next time, I call the function, I should have the result pointing to 3. Etc.
I would that when the function is called, the next node shouldn't be always head->next, but it should go on.

I have a function that takes as parameter the head;

```cpp
struct node
{
  int val;
  node*next;
}
node * create()
{
  node*tmp;
  node *head;
  for (int i = 1; i<6; i = i + 1)
  {
    tmp = new node;
    tmp->val = i;
    tmp->next = head;
    head = tmp;
  }
  return head;
}
node* NextNode(node*current)
{
  if (somethingHappens)
  {
    current = current->next; //this is wrong. Because it's important to not lose the pointer of head;
  }
  return current;
}
int main()

{
  node* result;
  node* another;
  node* head;
  head = create();
  result = NextNode(head);
  std::cout << result->val << std::endl;
  //I call again the function, giving always as paramter the head pointer
  another = NextNode(head);
  std::cout << another->val << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

So result->val should give 2 as result
and another->val should give 3. 
But obviously this is not happening, because head is fixed. Is there another way I can do this? 
The code is pseudocode of what I would like to do. Hope I have been clear, english is not my first language, so please, be patient.

Comment: This code is mostly C with the only c++ being the use of cout.  Suggest you embrace the c++ stl.  It takes care of reinventing the wheel so that you can get onto building an app.   Unless of course this is homework?

Comment: If you want to preserve `head`, call `NextHead()` with a copy of head first time. Second time call `NextHead()` with result returned by the first call

Comment: @kuro: Updating `head` isn't really a good idea as access to few nodes might be lost.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni, that is why I said to use a copy of header, say `curr_node` which will be initialized with `head`

Comment: Oh, right! I didn't notice your earlier comment.

Comment: yes i don't want to lose the head pointer, how it works the copy of head?

Comment: you need not create copy of a head. In your above example, as I mentioned in my answer, `result` is the best possible pointer to use again

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni, `NextNode()` changes the pointer. So, the first call will update `head`. A copy of `head` is needed.

Comment: Apparently, better alternative is to initialize `result` like `node* result = head;`. This you won't use extra memory like in creating copy of head. That would also require changing `result = NextNode(head);` to `result = NextNode(result);`

Comment: What if I would like to keep doing the reading nextnode? isn't there another way to do it?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: inside of the function there is, "somethingHappens", let's say that somethingHappens keep happening, I would like to be able to  keep reading the nextNode value, but the list that I keep passing on the main is always the list pointed by head, so unless I keep creating  variables, there is no way of keep reading the values on the list?

Answer (score 0):

Change `another = NextNode(head);` to `another = NextNode(result);`.
You are not passing the next node obtained from previous call while calling the `NextNode()` next time.

(*On a side note, I see that the code you posted is either not a working code or some code is missing and not posted; but the code is sufficient enough to understand your doubt and figure out a solution.*)